# Struggling when Changing the default Quilljs tooltip by an alert and how to affect HTML tags when I write Quillsjs on real Senario

Tags: quill, ngx-quill

> Hi I m trying to change the default tooltip related to the link tag  by a popup, so I started with an alert and then I will replace it With the Popup later.

I managed to show the alert when I click on   tag if it is already provided by default in the text loaded to quilljs editor is already  that in this codepen link : https://codepen.io/aymen_soussi_Expleo/pen/JjeqeOz

But I still have 2 problems, as I want to refactor it later to ngx-quill with Angular:

First, I don t like the current solution as I need to call separately the function showAlert(), I tried other solutions but I failed.

The second  Problem I have is to implement a checker that transform html tags written in live in the Quill Editor into HTML format meaning if I write in live   hello  it needs to be transformed automatically to the blue Link color

For first issue I tried so much to remove the showAlert() and called inside the definition of the toolbar say {link:showAlert()}, I think there is a way to integrate this solution in a separate quill module and then import that module or if there any other way to clean my code as I m defining the Quill in my angular app in a module file and I can t add any extra function in such a file.

For second problem I think Quill already provide a predefined API that can change html tags written in live to HTML format but I still did not find a good example